# intelliJ 11.1.4 - adding a jar to project only works 50%

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an Android project that uses some external libraries. The problem is that within intelliJ I can build the project and it runs fine, but the editor marks classes that come from the jars as unknown.

I've added the jars to the correct module (project structure -> module -> dependency) independently, from the libs directory, as classes, jar directory, etc. I've also tried to add them using project settings -> add libs, attach them to the module. But to no avail. I also tried to add them within the project explorer with right-click -> add library. Nothing works.

It was all fine before but now after a horrible IntelliJ crash it no longer works. This has happened to me twice now. And I loose a lot of time trying to fix this. Am I fighting an intelliJ bug here?

Comment: Does `File` | `Invalidate Caches` help?

Comment: You're a live saver CrazyCoder! I kept rebuilding the project thinking that would clean caches. I wasn't aware of Invalidate Caches. Please add this as an answer so I can accept it. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File` | `Invalidate Caches` is the first thing to try in similar cases.